# Calling async / await function and receiving a value back

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I have got a function in an API library that calls `firestore` and gets data back. This part works fine:

```
export const getUserByReferrerId = async id => {
  let doc = await firestore
    .collection(FIRESTORE_COLLECTIONS.USERS)
    .where('grsfId', '==', id)  
    .get()  
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log ("we found a doc");
        // use only the first document, but there could be more
        const snapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
        console.log ("snapshot", snapshot.id);
        return snapshot.id  // uid of the user
      }
    });
}
```

I am calling this library from a component. I have another function that runs on a button click. I cannot figure out **how to get the value** from the `async` api call.

I have tried this - a promise appears when I `console.log` the return:

```
testCreditFunction = (id) => {
    let uid = getUserByReferrerId(id).then(doc => { 
        console.log("uid1", doc);    
    });
}
```

I have also tried this - log shows null for `uid`.

```
testCreditFunction = (id) => {
    let uid = '';
    
    (async () => {
        uid = await getUserByReferrerId(id);
        console.log ("uid in the function", uid);
    })();
}
```

I have seen this question asked a few times and I have tried several of the answers and none are working for me. The odd thing is that I have done this same thing in other areas and I cannot figure out what the difference is.

Comment: You assign to `doc` but do not show any code that would `return` anything from `getUserByReferrerId`. For a caller to "get" something via `await` or `.then`, you need to return at all levels.

Comment: you need to return ```doc``` in ```getUserByReferrerID``` method.  Right now it's not returning anything, and that's probably why you're getting a promise returned instead of the value.

Comment: You get a `Promise` because the function is `async` and it has an `await`. That happens without needing to `return` anything. But to get a value out, you need to `return` that value. If you return a value, you *still* get a promise, but a promise that resolves to the value (with `.then` or `await`)

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/8376184)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your funtion to this.

```
export const getUserByReferrerId = async id => {
  return await firestore
  .collection(FIRESTORE_COLLECTIONS.USERS)
  .where('grsfId', '==', id)  
  .get();
}
```

Try getting data this way.

```
 testCreditFunction = (id) => {

 let querySnapshot = '';
        
    (async () => {
      querySnapshot = await getUserByReferrerId(id);
      const snapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
      console.log ("snapshot", snapshot.id);
  })();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  Worked perfectly!

Comment: I think you can mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice right off the bat is that you're mixing `async/await` & `.then/.error`. While it's not strictly forbidden it definitely makes things more difficult to follow.

As others have mentioned in the comments, you need to make a return for the promise to resolve (complete). Here's how you might write `getUserByReferrerId` (using async/await).

```js
const getUserByReferrerId = async id => {
  const usersRef = firestore.collection('users');
  const query = usersRef.where('grsfId', '==', id);

  const snapshot = await query.get();
  if (snapshot.empty) {
   console.log('no doc found');
   return;
  }

  console.log('doc found');
  const doc = snapshot.docs[0]; // use first result only (there might be more though)
  return doc.id
}
```

You'll notice how I split up the query building steps from the snapshot request. This was intentional as the only promised function in this is the `get` request.

Using this `getUserByReferrerID` can be done with a simple `await`. Just be sure to check that the result isn't undefined.

```
const userID = await getUserByReferrerId('someid')

if (!userID) {
  console.log('user not found');
}

console.log(`User ID is ${userID}`);
```

---

p.s - I would recommend renaming the function to `getUserIdByReferrerId` to more accurately reflect the fact that you're returning an ID and not a user doc. Alternatively, you can return the user object and leave the name as is.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I did try something similar before and ran into an issue where it didn't like the await in the calling area.  

Here is the button click code:

 <Button type="primary" onClick={() => {this.testCreditFunction("q00mvn")}}> 


And here is the error:

./src/pages/components/UserReferralInfo.js
  Line 105:  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

  103 |       console.log("in the function", id)
  104 | 
> 105 |       const userID = await getUserByReferrerId('someid')

Comment: I see the problem - the calling function also need async around it:

 (async () => {
      const userID = await getUserByReferrerId(id)

Comment: Yup, I purposefully didn't wrap it in a `(async ...)()` because I wasn't sure if you would have been using it in an async function already